# HTTP 404 The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. Tomcat Spring

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

Контроллер:

```
@Component
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BookController {
    private final BookDAO bookDAO;
    //private final BookValidator bookValidator;

    public BookController(BookDAO bookDAO) {
        this.bookDAO = bookDAO;
    }

    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String index(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("books", bookDAO.index());
        return "/books/index";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ru.viktor</groupId>
  <artifactId>booksProject</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
  <name>spring-mvc-app Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring6 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
      <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring6</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.33</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.11</version>
    </dependency>



  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>resources</directory>
        <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
        <includes>
          <include>application.properties</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <finalName>spring-mvc-app</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

При запуске проекта открывается http://localhost:8080 с Hello World, при переходе на http://localhost:8080/books/index отображается ошибка 404.

Comment: `@Component` -> `@Controller`. И плюс надо смотреть, как у вас настроены бины для работы со страницами и что вы вообще используете - просто JSP или какой-нибудь шаблонизатор. От этого будет зависеть то, что вы должны писать в `return` в методах контроллеров

Comment: @Byb вы меня спасаете уже второй раз. Был сонный, попутал. От души

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перепутал аннотации @Component и @Controller. Спасибо